# Ncurses and C++ screensaver

Tags: c++, arrays, ncurses

I'm trying to write a small program to make a sort of animation using ncurses. I’m new to all of this, mostly ncurses.

I want to fill the screen randomly with an X with a certain fore and background color using a bool 2D array. True (open) means that an X can be written to that spot. After the X is written there, the spots value changed to False (closed/filled) and it continues to look for True spots. After the ENTIRE screen in filled, it will just loop through all color pairs available in ncurses until I hit ctrl+c.I've tried a lot of things and most had failed or partially worked or compiled and done nothing. I'm new to this all, especially ncurses.I've hit a few walls that I'm very stuck on. Google has helped a little, but I'm still stuck.

How can I use ncurses "getyx" command and put those coordinates into a 2D array to check each element? Or should I use a different way to get screen coordinates and put them into my 2D array?

I wanted to use "int rand()" function to generate a random number/array element to check and fill or not fill. I thought I’d just % everything by 1 so it just checks everything. 10 / 1 = 10, 3/1 = 3, etc….would this work?

I’ve tried to get it to “sleep” in between writing colored X’s to the screen, but it pauses at the beginning and then does only the first color pair. I’m not sure how to fix that, many nested loops maybe?

```
COLOR_PAIR(1);
attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));

move(10, 20);

addstr("Hello");

sleep(5);

COLOR_PAIR(2);

attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));

addstr("Hello");

refresh();

sleep(5);

endwin();
```

In general, I'm confused with ncurses and some of the looping logic. I've asked friends who are full blown experienced programmers, devs, software people....most haven't even heard of the ncurses library.

Are there some good tutorials on ncurses for these types of things? Any other examples or resources I should look at for similar programs? I've done tic tac toe before, but this is the entire screen and not just a box drawn by a lonely 2D array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where's your code, and what specific problem are you having with it?

Comment: My problem is how to find the x.y of the screen with ncurses or c++ and use it as my indexes in a 2D array. I have no code at the moment because I'm trying to understand the concept and how to use ncurses.

Comment: Nothing appears on the screen until you call `refresh`, so you should be calling it before every `sleep` call.

Comment: Also, `mvinch` and `mvwinch` can be used to read Ncurses's internal data structures to see which characters are supposed to be at which coordinates, and what attributes (including color) they have, so there's no need to create your own data structures. All this business about True (open) and False (closed) is unnecessary. If `mvinch(y,x)` says there's an "X" there, then your program should act like there's an "X" there.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to ncurses and haven't been able to explore everything.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the state of you game in an internal structure, not rely on the terminal screen and try to read it back to step to the next state.  The terminal is just the rendering tool, not the state itself.

Comment: I'm sort of new at this so I'm not sure what you mean. I have a header file with a class and a main file that calls the function (the one I'm trying to make here). Inside the class is my void function, 2 private members for the delay (sleep) time and for the X. I also have a constructor in there and initialize it by reading a char and time from an input file. Right now I'm confused on getting the x,y of the entire screen, putting those into a bool 2D array, getting a random element from there, checking it, and changing the value to false.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you've got it all wrong when it comes to choosing random coordinates. That should be done as follows:

```
/* Using a macro to follow the style of the Ncurses library. */
#define randyx(y,x) {                  \
    int max_y, max_x;                  \
    getmaxyx(stdscr, max_y, max_x);    \
    y=rand() % max_y;                  \
    x=rand() % max_x;                  \
}
```

(Note: Using the % operator to limit the range of a random number results
in numbers that are not random enough for things like random-generating passwords, but it's good enough for our purposes.)

Then, whenever you need random coordinates, you do this:

```
int y,x;
randyx(y,x);
/* y and x are random screen coordinates from here. */
```

The next thing you need to be able to do is get the character and color
that are already at a given location (because you want to invoke special behavior if you've already put an X at a given spot). Instead of creating your own 2D array to do this, you can let Ncurses handle it for you, since Ncurses already keeps track of what is (supposed to be) on the screen:

```
chtype color_and_char = mvinch(y,x);
```

The color, character, and all other Curses attributes are mushed together in a single integer. To separate them, some macros are handy:

```
#define CH_CHAR(ch) (ch & A_CHARTEXT)
#define CH_COLOR(ch) (ch & A_COLOR)
#define CH_ATTR(ch) (ch & A_ATTRIBUTES)
```

So now you can check if there's an X there:

```
if(CH_CHAR(color_and_char) == 'X') {
     /* Change the color. You're on your own in figuring out the
        correct value for MAX_COLOR_PAIR. My guess would be 64.

        0x100 is the same thing as COLOR_PAIR(1). */
     put_x(y,x,(CH_COLOR(color_and_char)+0x100) % COLOR_PAIR(MAX_COLOR_PAIR));
} else {
    put_x(y,x,COLOR_PAIR(1));
}
```

To put an X of a given color at a given location:

```
void put_x(int y, int x, int color_pair) {
    move(y,x);
    attron(color_pair);
    addch('X');
    refresh();
}
```

To change the color of an X that is already there, just call `put_x` with the new color.